# Exception handling in spark udf

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have spark user defined function which returns date in certain format

```
val getEventdatetime: (String,String) => String = (strLogArrivalDate,strEventDatetime) =>  {

        val year = strLogArrivalDate.split('-')(0).toString() //get year part
        val strEventDatetime1 = year + " " + strEventDatetime
        val inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss")

        new Timestamp(inputFormat.parse(strEventDatetime1).getTime).toString()

    }

    // Defining spark UserDefinedFunction
    val getEventdatetimeUDF = udf[String,String,String](getEventdatetime)
```

I'm receiving the input dates from some logs, if there is any problem in date value, my application fails.
For e.g.

```
val strEventDatetime1="2019 Jul 01 00:00:00" //works fine
val strEventDatetime1="2019 Jul 01 k 00:00:00" //throws error
```

I've tried wrapping everything in try/catch but it doesn't work

```
val getEventdatetime: (String,String) => String = (strLogArrivalDate,strEventDatetime) =>  {

      try {
        val year = strLogArrivalDate.split('-')(0).toString() //get year part
        val strEventDatetime1 = year + " " + strEventDatetime
        val inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss")

        new Timestamp(inputFormat.parse(strEventDatetime1).getTime).toString()
      }catch{
        case e: Exception => println(e.getMessage())
        "1900-01-01 00:00::"
      }

    }
```

Calling the UDF:

```
// Adding new column "event_datetime1" to DF , it's value is derived from log_arrival_time & event_datetime
val dfProcessed = dfValidLogs1.withColumn("event_datetime1", getEventdatetimeUDF.apply($"log_arrival_time",$"event_datetime"))
```

This is giving me '**Task not serializable**' error. I've limited knowledge of how spark udf works. What will the best way to handle error inside the udf?
Thanks in advance.

**Stack trace for error**

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:345)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:335)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2299)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:844)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:843)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex(RDD.scala:843)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:608)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ForeachSink.addBatch(ForeachSink.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$3$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:475)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$3.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:473)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:472)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:133)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:117)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:279)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.lang.Object
Serialization stack:
- object not serializable (class: java.lang.Object, value: java.lang.Object@3238cce)
- field (class: com.sb.spark.accesspoint.AccesspointAnalysis$accesspointAnalysis$$anonfun$6, name: nonLocalReturnKey1$1, type: class java.lang.Object)
- object (class com.sb.spark.accesspoint.AccesspointAnalysis$accesspointAnalysis$$anonfun$6, <function2>)
- element of array (index: 9)
- array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 17)
- field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10, name: references$1, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
- object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10, <function2>)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:342)
```

Comment: If the input is invalid for e.g. val strEventDatetime1="2019 Jul 01 k 00:00:00" , the catch block should handle the error and return default value "1900-01-01 00:00:00"

Comment: How are you calling an udf? If you are just trying change the format, I would not have used udf. Thats why its better to add some input and output so that I can help rewriting the udf or with built in functions.

Comment: What are `com.sb.spark.accesspoint.AccesspointAnalysis$accesspointAnalysis$$anonfun$6` and `references$1`? Do you recognize where they could come from?

Comment: How do you execute the code? Is this as part of a Spark app or `spark-shell`?